# SSRS default zoom for report send through subscription

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to set default zoom level for a few reports. I know about `rc` parameter, but I don't show them through browser so it's useless for me. Instead I use SSRS subscriptions and send them as excel attachments. Is there any way to set default zoom level for such report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the default zoom on an Excel spreadsheet emailed to a user? No.